# Replace \ with / With an Inputted Directory in Python

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to replace an inputted paths' "\" with "/" to avoid a escaping character that messes with my code.

```
path = input("Enter the Directory: )
path.replace('\' , '/')
```

First off the reason I want to do this is because when the user inputs the path (copying and pasting it from Windows Explorer), it is in the C:\User\Folder convention which is giving me issues later on in my program when I have to output the real path and it gives me C:\User\Folder with double "\" because of the raw string method.

My path.replace() is not working because the '\' is thinking it is an escaping character. I also tried:

```
path.replace((r'\'), '/')
```

But the entire input turns into a string and does not work. Anyone have advice to do this, or another way to get an inputted path that is copied to have / instead of \? Thanks!

Comment: just use `path.replace('\\' , '/')`

Comment: If you want the character "\" you need to double escape "\\". Escaping cancels the normal meaning of a character; in this case the normal meaning  of the escape is to escape. -_-

Comment: `path = path.replace('\\', '/')`

Comment: Interesting, newer to python so thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem starts earlier. The OP states "_it gives me C:\User\Folder with double "\"_ ". I don't see how this could happen if you don't print the representation of the string. Just a `print(path)` should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` returns a copy of the string, you'll need to assign the result to the variable

```
path = input("Enter the Directory: ")
path = path.replace('\\' , '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
path.replace('\\', '/')
```